# How to apply a negative strength modifier to a critical hit?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, critical-hit

Considering a character with a strength modifier of -2 with a weapon that deals 1d3 damages, how to calculate the damages in case of critical?

I can see the following possibilities:

- 2d3-4 (minimum 1 nonlethal)
- 1d3-2 (minimum 1 nonlethal) + 1d3-2 (minimum 1 nonlethal)

related: [About damage calculations for a weak character](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/87285/about-damage-calculations-for-a-weak-character)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your second example is a correct one, because Critical Hits section says:

> A critical hit means that you **roll** your damage **more than once**, with all your usual bonuses, and add the rolls together.

It is spelled even clearer in Multiplying Damage section:

> Roll the damage (with all modifiers) multiple times and total **the results**.

Therefore, such a character inflicts minimum of 2 points of non-lethal damage on a successful hit with a weapon having x2 critical multiplier.

Comment: That first quoted statement mentions only adding bonuses, whereas a negative strength modifier is a penalty.

Comment: @ChrisPy Probably similar issue to Strength Bonus section. Header with the word "bonus" is folloved by "When you hit with a melee or thrown weapon, including a sling, add your Strength **modifier** to the damage result".